# mysql read replica master database performance

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

Can having a read replica (or multiple read replicas) of a MySQL master database affect the performance of the master database? What if the read replica is located in a different geographical region?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, but generally it should not be that impactful.  You do have more i/o overhead to publish the binary logs, and the server itself has to handle communications with slave servers.  This does not come for free in terms of overall resources consumed on the server.

That being said, on most sizable databases, this should represent a small percentage of overall server resources and should not impact performance greatly if you still have appropriate amount of memory allocated to indexes and your cpu and disk performance is such that you are not getting into iowait state.

The type of query load on the DB also will determine the impact of replication.

You can check out this article on the excellent mysqlperformance blog from Percona for an example of a case where depending on the DB load, replication can be more impactful.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/01/16/how-expensive-is-mysql-replication-for-the-master/